# How to reduce the number of displayed "changes" when running Ansible?

Tags: ansible

When running my Ansible playbook on a number of machines regularly, I always get numerous "changes" displayed even if nothing is changed (anymore).

This can have different reasons. For example one simple reason is registering variables:

```
tasks:
- name: Fetch docker_compose_version
  shell: docker-compose --version
  register: docker_compose_version
```

This block results in

```
TASK [Fetch docker_compose_version] ********************************************************************************
changed: [mysrv]
```

I would like the only see a change if there has really been changed something on the machine. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If there is not "global" answer to my question, please tell me. I will change the title to something like "How to avoid ansible printing unnecessairy 'changes' when registering variables?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what `changed_when` is for. For example:

```
- name: Fetch docker_compose_version
  shell: docker-compose --version
  register: docker_compose_version
  changed_when: false
```

For scripts and commands you need to define the condition yourself (there is no magic behind, regular modules handle everything manually too). Have a look at [Overriding The Changed Result](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_error_handling.html#overriding-the-changed-result).

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped. I never "saw" this section in the manual. fine. Another example for `changed_when` is:

      - name: Set vim as default
    command: update-alternatives --set editor /usr/bin/vim.basic
    register: command_result
    environment:
      LANG: C
    changed_when: "'using' in command_result.stdout"